# How can I add org.eclipse.ui.ide to my eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I would like to use CNF in my RCP application, but I need add some plugins before.
I read this [link](http://www.cpuidle.de/blog/?attachment_id=50) about how use CNF in RCP but I don't know how add required plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you must add this plug-in to your target definition. You can do that in the eclipse preferences under `Windows -> Preferences -> Plug-in-Developement -> Target Platform -> Edit -> Add` and select the folder which contains your plug-in.